# How to transform Iterable<Map.Entry<A,B>> to Map<A,B> using Guava?

Tags: java, guava

I was able to do that by doing the following :

```
Iterable<Map.Entry<A,B>> entryIterable
Map<A, B> aBMap = newHashMap();
for (Map.Entry<A, B> aBEntry : entryIterable) {
   aBMap.put(aBEntry.getKey() , aBEntry.getValue());
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this using Guava?

Comment: I don't think there is.

Comment: You Will _love_ closures in Java 8.

Answer (score 6):

No, this was refused, see the [Idea Graveyard](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/IdeaGraveyard#create_a_map_from_an_Iterable%3CPair%3E_,_Iterable%3CMap.Entr):

> **Create a map from an `Iterable<Pair>`, `Iterable<Map.Entry>`, `Object[]` (alternating keys and values), or from `List<K>` + `List<V>`**
>
> Note that we may still add `ImmutableMap.copyOf(Iterable<Entry>)`.

Comment: Note this is implemented in [issue 320](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=320) and will be included in version 19.0

Answer (score 1):

Only a wee bit easier:

```
ImmutableMap.Builder<A, B> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
for (Map.Entry<A, B> entry : entries) {
  builder.put(entry); // no getKey(), no getValue()
}
return builder.build();
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been implemented in Guava 19.0, see [ImmutableMap.copyOf(Iterable)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#copyOf(java.lang.Iterable)).